# ECO templates with Backbone + Marionette but without Rails

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, eco

I am trying to use [ECO templates](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) with [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) and [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) but without [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/).  Rather, I am using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) managing my front-end asset pipeline.

**How do I load ECO templates?**

Here is what a simple Marionette view looks like for me using [Underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/) templates:

```
define ['cs!app', 'requirejs-tpl!./templates/message.tpl'], (App, message) ->
  App.module 'About.Show', (Module, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
    class Module.MessageView extends Marionette.ItemView
      className:  'message-view'
      tagName:    'div'
      template:   message
```

I'm guessing I need to set the template key to a ECO template file and then override the view's render method -- but I am not sure as I believe I must precompile the ECO file first...

Things I am going to try:

- [django-pipeline](https://github.com/vshjxyz/django-pipeline-eco)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is to install `eco` via `npm` and then run something like `eco -i JST form.eco`.  Then, you assign `JST['form']` to the view's `template` attribute.  Setting this up manually for multiple templates is probably a bid job, so it is probably best to look at something like django-pipeline.